# ruby irb on windows using gitbash shell - can't use arrow keys to modify command input?

Tags: ruby, shell, irb

when I do rails console my git bash shell permits me to use up arrow to recall commands, and use left/right arrows to modify the text I'm entering

when I run `irb` the shell ignores backspace and arrow keys

I'm not sure why the arrow keys would work fine in the shell for rails console but not when running `irb`?

Answer (score 4):

As I just wrote in the related [Backspace and arrow keys aren't working in IRB(Git Bash console) on windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660209/backspace-and-arrow-keys-arent-working-in-irbgit-bash-console-on-windows-mach):

running irb with **--noreadline** solved this problem for me:

```
irb --noreadline
```

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you running?  You may need install the GNU Readline Library and reinstall ruby.

Comment: win xp ... if your theory is correct, does it make sense that it would work for 'rails console' but not for 'irb'?

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help!

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following command fixed the problem for me on Windows

```
gem install wirble win32console
```

Comment: thx! (tho I moved to a mac after one window problem after another)

Answer (score 1):

As documented here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/HgswOz1T-eE, use the below command/alias:

```
alias irb="ruby -S irb"
```