# Can't see irb prompt when running rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and currently following this guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I am at the part where I need to run the `rails console` command to get the irb prompt, but instead I only get this weird `Switch to inspect mode.` statement. The image is in a link because i'm not allowed to embed them yet.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0SDR.png)

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What platform are you on? Are you running win bash? Have you searched for something like "rails console switch to inspect mode" and tried any of the found solutions?

Comment: I am on windows, running on git bash. Nothing I have searched have turned out to be the same or even similar problem.

Comment: It seems like it's the *exact* same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38132561/438992 etc. If you believe it's not the same you may want to edit your question to explain why solutions with the identical environment and symptoms did not work for you.

Comment: I found this post https://teamtreehouse.com/community/i-cannot-get-into-the-rails-console-keeps-returning-switch-to-inspect-mode-then-freezing-until-i-ctrl-c which indicates that gitbash is faulty with rails console. It works on Windows Powershell though.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `rb-readline` gem and see weather updating it will solve the problem. Some versions of this gem have been known to cause this issue